# how to set bottom bar in the webview

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I have been trying to find a solution of how to add a bottom bar in the webview but couldn't find a solution till now . Any help is welcomed .

This is my activity_main.xml file:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

  <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:id="@+id/activity_main"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      xmlns:design="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      tools:context=".MainActivity"
      android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
      android:orientation="vertical">





<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>



<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    design:menu="@menu/menu_navigation"
    />





  </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

### mainActivity.java

This is my mainActivity file. I am still new in java and I am to add different features in my application including handling calls share but the problem I met was the bottom bar it looks it doesn't work

```
     public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
     WebView web;
     ProgressBar progressBar;
     ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
     private BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;
     private TextView infoTextView;
     private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
     public ValueCallback<Uri[]> uploadMessage;
     public static final int REQUEST_SELECT_FILE = 100;
     private final static int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 1;

    @Override
     protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                Intent intent) {
       if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {
         if (null == mUploadMessage) return;
         Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK ? null
                : intent.getData();
          mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
         mUploadMessage = null;
      }
  }


        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
           infoTextView =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.infoTextView);
           bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) 
          findViewById(R.id.bottom);
          bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new 
    BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
           @Override
           public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

             if (item.getItemId() ==R.id.startItem){
                infoTextView.setText(R.string.start);
             }else if (item.getItemId() ==R.id.secondItem){
                 infoTextView.setText(R.string.second);
             }else if (item.getItemId() ==R.id.thirdItem){
                 infoTextView.setText(R.string.third);
             }else if (item.getItemId() ==R.id.fourthItem){
                infoTextView.setText(R.string.fourth);
             }else if (item.getItemId() ==R.id.fifthItem){
                 infoTextView.setText(R.string.fifth);
             }
             return false;
         }
       });

        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
         progressBar = new ProgressBar(this);

       web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings= web.getSettings();
       web.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

       web = new WebView(this);
      web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
      //enable webview perfomance
       web.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
      web.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
      webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);


  webSettings.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS);
      webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
      webSettings.setSavePassword(true);
       webSettings.setSaveFormData(true);
      webSettings.setEnableSmoothTransition(true);
     web.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    web.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient());
    web.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()


      {



         public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
              progressBar.setProgress(progress);
             if (progress == 100) {
                 progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

             } else {
                 progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
        }




         //The undocumented magic method override
         //Eclipse will swear at you if you try to put @Override here
          // For Android 3.0+
         public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {

             mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
             Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
             i.setType("image/*");
            MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, 
         "File Chooser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);

        }

        // For Android 3.0+
         public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback uploadMsg, String 
         acceptType) {
            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
             Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
             i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
             i.setType("*/*");
             MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(
                     Intent.createChooser(i, "File Browser"),
                    FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
        }

        //For Android 4.1
         public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String 
  acceptType, String capture) {
             mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
              Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
             i.setType("image/*");
            MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser
    (i,  "File Chooser"), MainActivity.FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);

        }

    });

     setContentView(web);

}


 public class MyAppWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {


    //ProgressDialogue
     ProgressDialog pd = null;

     @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
         pd=new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pd.setTitle("Chargement");
         pd.setMessage("Veuillez patienter...");
         pd.show();
         super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }


     @Override
     public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
         // mProgressDialog.dismiss();
         pd.dismiss();
         animate(view);
        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         super.onPageFinished(view, url);

    }


     private void animate(final WebView view) {
        Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(),
                 android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
        view.startAnimation(anim);
    }



     @Override
 public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

      /*  {
             view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
             mProgressDialog.setTitle("Chargement");
            mProgressDialog.show();
             mProgressDialog.setMessage("Veuillez patienter... " );

        }*/


          if (url.startsWith("tel:")) {
             Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL,
                     Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
         }else if(url.startsWith("http:") || url.startsWith("https:")) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
        }

         //Load the dialer
         else if (url.startsWith(WebView.SCHEME_TEL)) {


                 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                 startActivity(intent);


         } else if (url.startsWith(WebView.SCHEME_TEL) ||
                 url.startsWith("facebook://") ||
                url.startsWith("whatsapp://") ||
                 url.startsWith(WebView.SCHEME_MAILTO) ||
                url.startsWith(WebView.SCHEME_GEO) ||
                 url.startsWith("maps:")) {


                 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                 startActivity(intent);


         }return true;
     }



     @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
         web.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error.html");
        super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
    }


}


      @Override
     public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
      { //if back key is pressed
       if((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)&& web.canGoBack())
      {
        web.goBack();
        return true;

      }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

      }



     public void onBackPressed() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            MainActivity.this);

      // set title
       alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Fermer");

    // set dialog message
     alertDialogBuilder
             .setMessage("Voulez-vous vraiment quitter ?")
            .setCancelable(false)
             .setPositiveButton("Oui", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
       {
                  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                     // if this button is clicked, close
                    // current activity
                     MainActivity.this.finish();
                }
            })
        .setNegativeButton("Non", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                     // if this button is clicked, just close
                    // the dialog box and do nothing
                     dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

        // create alert dialog
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

       // show it
      alertDialog.show();
    }



    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/activity_main"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  xmlns:design="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  tools:context=".MainActivity"
  android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
  android:orientation="vertical">


  <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>



  <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    design:menu="@menu/menu_navigation"
    />
  </RelativeLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Hope it helps !